# Classloader used in Android Application

Tags: android, initialization, classloader, invoke

I ran into a thorny problem in dealing with Android applications - loading class from a .zip or .dex in an app. I cant deal with the `Classloader` problem. Please help me, thanks.
I'm trying to load a class from a zip, but the class(such as Android provider or something like that) needs to be loaded when the program starts. So, I have to leave a file in my programs, for example, with packages `com.example.androidprovider` and file TestProvider.java.

```
package com.example.androidprovider;
public class TestProvider extends ContentProvider {
public static final String AUTHORY="com.lcz.tst";
      DBHelper dbHelp;
      SQLiteDatabase sq;
      @Override
      public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
                sq.delete(DBHelper.TABLE, selection, selectionArgs);
                return 0;
      }
      ...
      @Override
      public boolean onCreate() {
                dbHelp=new DBHelper(getContext(),null, null, 1);
                sq=dbHelp.getWritableDatabase();
                Log.i("TestProvider", "text");
                return true;
      }
}
```

In my .zip file, I package a class with package `com.example.androidprovider` and class name `TestProvider`.(The two class is different, and the second class is the class I really need.)

```
package com.example.androidprovider;
public class TestProvider extends ContentProvider {
      public static final String AUTHORY="com.lcz.tst";
      DBHelper dbHelp;
      SQLiteDatabase sq;
      @Override
      public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
                sq.delete(DBHelper.TABLE, selection, selectionArgs);
                return 0;
      }
      ...
      @Override
      public boolean onCreate() {
                dbHelp=new DBHelper(getContext(),null, null, 1);
                sq=dbHelp.getWritableDatabase();
                Log.i("Original Provider", "This is the original!!!");
                return true;
      }
}
```

Now, this is my loader code.

```
public void loadDex(String strActivity){
      final File optimizedDexOutputPath = oriActivity.getDir("outdex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
      // Initialize the class loader with the secondary dex file.
      //dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath() is the path there the .zip is,
      DexClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),
                optimizedDexOutputPath.getAbsolutePath(),
                libPath,
                this.getClass().getClassLoader());
      Class<?> cls;
      try {
                cls = cl.loadClass("com.example.androidprovider.TestProvider");
                Object instant = cls.newInstance();
                Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("onCreate");
                method.invoke(instant);
      }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

I checked the logcat, but the log always shows **"TestProvider text"**. So, this means that my loader code failed. I think the reason is that, my application initials a `com.example.androidprovider.TestProvider` (the first piece of code) class, and the loader loads a different class with the same package and name, so the second class cannot be loaded successfully.

But i really need to load the second class. Can i use some ways to start the second class? 
Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get why you don't load the original in the first place but anyway. You could place a Proxy Class in the application which deligates the method calls to your "original" class. But you need to use reflections!

```
package com.example.androidprovider;
public class TestProviderProxy extends ContentProvider {
   public boolean onCreate() {
            // use reflections here -> GOOGLE IT
            // something with clazz = context.getClassloader().loadClass(
            // "com.example.androidprovider.TestProvider");
            //  method = clazz.getMethod("onCreate")
            return method.invoke();
  }
}

package com.example.androidprovider;
public class TestProvider extends ContentProvider {
   public boolean onCreate() {
            dbHelp=new DBHelper(getContext(),null, null, 1);
            sq=dbHelp.getWritableDatabase();
            Log.i("Original Provider", "This is the original!!!");
            return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
Maybe this can work well.In my example, the first TestProviderProxy should change as few as possible. This is just a piece of test code, actually, maybe I cannt get the source code of the first TestProviderProxy. But it must be initialized, because of the AndroidMenifest.xml file in an Android Applicaiton. So I have to write an alternative TestProviderProxy(the second) to load the actual TestProviderProxy(the first). I didnt thought  of re-writing my alternative TestProviderProxy, I'll have a try. Thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, I know the reflection is really powerful. so, can I have some ways to cover the first class with the second class during the runtime execution? I thinks maybe this can work as well by modify some data of system layer with reflection, but I didn't know what kind of data should be modified. Thanks.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are trying to achieve... but I hope it helped you. Yes reflections are "powerful" but the system itself runs on native code and your Application runs in a SandBox. You can't just change "some data" to make everthing work.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I use this method, and the original provider can works. But, after that, my activity cannot work out...I'll check whether there is something wrong in my code or not...

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to do this would be to modify the base context's classloader by overriding attachBaseContext() in your Application class.

```
protected void attachBaseContext(Context base)
{
   Log.i(loggerName, "Attaching base context");
   super.attachBaseContext(base);

   // Modify base.getClassLoader() via reflection.
   // Load classes as normal without having to tinker around with loadClass etc.

}
```